# cannot extract the p_value from lqmm function in R loop

Tags: r, model, extract

I am running multiple models via loop using lqmm function in R And I want to get the P-value from each models. Here is a simple data set contains two dependent variables.

```
data <- structure(list(y1 = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7), y2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 8, 7, 8), x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), weight = c(0.9401069, 1.2730856, 0.985858, 4.1602805, 1.6042408, 1.0452717, 0.9784276, 1.5199646)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))
```

First, I ran a single model and extracted the P-value using the following code:

```
model <- lqmm(fixed= y1 ~ x, random = ~1, tau=0.5, group=id,data=data,weights=data$weight,na.action=na.omit)
summary(model)$tTable[2,5]
```

It worked well.

Since I have multiple dependent variables, I need to use loop function to run them. Here is what I tried to run them automatically.

```
for (j in 1:2) {
  form <- formula(paste(names(data)[j], "~ x" ))
  model <- lqmm(form, random=~1, group=id, weights=data$weight, data=data, tau=0.5, na.action=na.omit)
  print(summary(model)$tTable[2,5])
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. The error is "Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable".

But If I just print the two coefficients, the code below worked:

```
for (j in 1:2) {
  form <- formula(paste(names(data)[j], "~ x" ))
  model <- lqmm(form, random=~1, group=id, weights=data$weight, data=data, tau=0.5, na.action=na.omit)
  print(coef(model))
}
```

But the information that I also need is the P-values. I failed to find the answer in google. Could someone do me a favor?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `eval()` around `form`:

```
set.seed(1234)
for(j in 1:2) {
  form <- formula(paste(names(data)[j], "~ x" ))
  model <- lqmm(eval(form), random=~1, group=id, weights=data$weight, data=data, tau=0.5, na.action=na.omit)
  print(summary(model)$tTable[2,5])
}
#[1] 7.055214e-07
#[1] 0.06919567
```

Comment: Hi Dan, it worked! Thanks so much for your time and help! It's amazing! :D

Comment: To my great surprise it works, `identical(form, eval(form))` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: I think (although I'm not certain) that this issue is a result of how `summary.lqmm()` handles `object$call[["fixed"]]`.  Thus, this is more the "fault" of the summary method, and not so much "your fault".